# Can I port a Win CE app to Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-ce

I have a requirement to port a C# application developed on Win CE to Windows Phone 8. Can we port directly from Win CE, or do we need to tweak/develop from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides [porting resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394031%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) from a few platforms (Android, iOS, and XAML, as of this writing). Windows CE is not among them.

All you can do is to create the app from the scratch using the Windows Phone 8 API
in Visual Studio 2012.